# How do I make this post request in iOS objective c using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking, twilio, afnetworking-2

I need to make a POST request equivalent to this from [twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) in iOS to send SMS

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659/Messages.json \
-d "Body=Jenny%20please%3F%21%20I%20love%20you%20<3" \
-d "To=%2B15558675309" \
-d "From=%2B14158141829" \
-u 'AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659:{AuthToken}'
```

This is what I have:

```
NSString *kTwilioSID = @"AC5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
NSString *kTwilioSecret = @"SECRET";
NSString *kFromNumber = @"+14158141829";
NSString *kToNumber = @"+15558675309";
NSString *kMessage = @"Jenny please?! I love you <3";


NSString *twilioURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%@/Messages.json", kTwilioSID, kTwilioSecret, kTwilioSID];
NSDictionary *params = @ {@"account" :kTwilioSID, @"from":kFromNumber, @"to":kToNumber, @"body":kMessage };

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:twilioURL parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
 }
      failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

It is failing with the error, "Request failed: bad request (400)", and sms doesn't get sent also
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to use

```
[manager POST:twilioURL parameters:params ....
```

This method doesn't worked for me. Instead, here a sample of code that work :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://myurl/actionToperform"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//1
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"name\" : \"%@\", \"polygon\" : [%@]}",[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text, concatCoord] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//post
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //Do things if succesfull
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Do things when you've got an error
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Note that I use JSON in this code to format my parameters (1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed but you have to set the `serializerRequest` on your `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` object.

If I'm correct the reason for this error is that you are not setting the header field. Do something like this.

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSString pairString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", someRandomId];

NSData pairData = [pairString dataUsingEncoding NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *serializerVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pairData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

[requestSerializer setValue: serializerVal forHTTPHeaderField:@"Auth"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager setRequestSerializer:requestSerializer];
```